# Can one SQL query get me one row from a many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to find an SQL query to end up with 1 row containing an article title and its associated keywords.

```
Articles
-ArticleID PK
-ArticleTitle
-ArticleBody

Keywords
-KeywordID PK
-Keyword UNIQUE

Keyword_Article
-KeywordID PK
-ArticleID PK
```

Is this possible without multiple queries in PHP?

What I have which gives me as many rows as there are keywords per article

```
SELECT Article.ArticleID, 
Article.ArticleTitle, 
Keywords.Keyword, 
Keywords.KeywordID
FROM Article 
LEFT JOIN Keyword_Article
ON (Keyword_Article.ArticleID = Article.ArticleID)
LEFT JOIN Keywords
ON (Keyword_Article.KeywordID = Keywords.KeywordID)
WHERE Article.ArticleID='example'
```

I'm curious to see how and if it can be done with 1 SQL query.

Comment: Sure. Check out GROUP_CONCAT to return the article id and a list of keywords concatenated into one string.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a SQL statement that returns a variable number of columns.  So, you can't put each keyword in a separate column where the number of columns would vary by the article (unless you use dynamic SQL).

You can concatenate the keywords together into a single column using `group_concat`:

```
SELECT Article.ArticleID, Article.ArticleTitle, 
       group_concat(Keywords.Keyword separator ', ') as keywords
FROM Article  LEFT JOIN
     Keyword_Article
     ON Keyword_Article.ArticleID = Article.ArticleID EFT JOIN
     Keywords
     ON Keyword_Article.KeywordID = Keywords.KeywordID
WHERE Article.ArticleID = 'example'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT Article.ArticleID, 
   Article.ArticleTitle, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(Keywords.Keyword) as Keywords
FROM Article 
   LEFT JOIN Keyword_Article
      ON (Keyword_Article.ArticleID = Article.ArticleID)
   LEFT JOIN Keywords
      ON (Keyword_Article.KeywordID = Keywords.KeywordID)
WHERE Article.ArticleID='example'
```

In your query you're returning the KeywordId as well.  You can use GROUP_CONCAT on those as well, but I suspect they wouldn't be needed.

Good luck.